# How to get distinct rows faster from a huge table?

Tags: sql, performance, oracle, group-by, distinct

I have a huge table which contains about 250 million rows. I have only SELECT privilege to this table. My intention is to query distinct records from a specific columns. I'm using a query

```
select var1, count(*)
from hr.hugetable
group by var1
```

This query takes about 15 minutes to complete. There is no index on var1 and I'm not able to add it. Is there a way to refine this query to fetch results faster? This query would also do it (I do not need count the record, only distinct values), but I think it is not faster.

```
select distinct Var1
from hr.hugetable
```

Comment: You think `distinct` is not faster, or you've tested that it isn't? (`distinct` is not a function, incidentally; it applies across all the selected columns, so the brackets are not needed and it should be `select distinct var1`). Whatever you do you have to pull every record from the table, since it isn't indexed, so the difference will be how Oracle holds and sorts the data - explain plan will tell you more. I think you're looking at a `HASH GROUP` vs. `HASH UNIQUE`, but the details will depend on your version and platform. 15 minutes sounds a long time though.

Comment: Cant you ask your DBA to better index the table? They have many tools that helps them in that task

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should talk to your DBA about your options, including indexing the column, and potentially more involved possibilities like a materialized view, if it's a frequently-executed query.

One possibility to consider is to parallelise the query, but be aware that this could actually slow it down depending on where the bottleneck is. There's a [white paper from Oracle on parallelisation](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/datawarehouse/twp-parallel-execution-fundamentals-133639.pdf).

In principle you could add the [`parallel` hint](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/sql_elements006.htm#SQLRF50801):

```
select /*+ parallel */ distinct var1
from hr.hugetable
```

You should discuss that with your DBA too, particularly the degree of parallelism (DOP) to use, and whether automatic DOP is appropriate. Also read up on what it does [in the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16638/hintsref.htm#CHDJIGDG), and compare the explain plans and timings - including at different DOP - to see what's appropriate. You don't want to risk impacting other users with what you're doing, so approach with caution, and with the DBA's involvement.